# Regexp for substitution of anything other than numbers and 'N/A'

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string:

```
my $str = "asd na ann nna aannaa NA 10012 3212and123 complan-boy 
           NANANANA n/a n/a nn/a na/a n/a/a";
```

I am trying to write a regexp that will remove everything other than numbers and `N/A` or `NA`.

For this I need to make ***negative*** of this regexp as `/(n\/a|na|\d+)/i`.

I tried this regexp:

```
s/[^(na|n\/a|\d+)]//gi
```

which finally boils down to this:

```
s/[^\d+na()\/|]//ig;
```

What do I do?

Comment: Instead of removal, how about matching what you want instead?

Comment: The square brackets `[]` define a character class, not a whole match.

Comment: @nhahtdh: If we can match, why can't we replace!

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma: Replace means matching the complement set, which is not always easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach is to find any stuff that is followed by n/a or digits (or the end of the string), then replace it with only the n/a or digits portion.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = "asd na ann nna aannaa NA 10012 3212and123 complan-boy 
           NANANANA n/a n/a nn/a na/a n/a/a";

$str =~ s#.*?(n/?a|\d+|\z)#$1#gis;

print $str;
```

`/s` enables single-line mode, allowing `.*` to match across newlines.

In general, **negative** matches in regexes tend to be quite difficult.  Most negative match problems can actually be expressed as a **positive** match, and doing so is usually simpler.

Comment: This gave me `100123212123n/an/an/an/a/a`. This contains extra `/a` at the end.

Comment: `$str =~ s#.*?(n/?a|\d+|\z)#$1#gis;` ?

Comment: @dan1111: Don't we need `\z` as suggested by @neil slater?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in some comments, the elegant way is to take what you want to keep, and forget about the rest:

```
use Test::More tests => 1;
my $str = "asd na ann nna aannaa NA 10012 3212and123 complan-boy 
           NANANANA n/a n/a nn/a na/a n/a/a";
my $replaced = join '' => $str =~ m{n/?a|\d+}gi;
is $replaced, 'nananaNA100123212123NANANANAn/an/an/anan/a';
```

I find this quite simple and maintainable in comparision with complex lookarounds. All you have to know is that in list context, a global regex match that doesn't define capture groups returns a list of all matched substrings. E.g. `"foo" =~ /o/g` would evaluate to `"o", "o"` in list context.
This list is concatenated and then represents the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/[^na\d]|n(?!\/?a)|(?<!n)(?<!n\/)a//ig
```

Note: I don't think you can replace `(?<!n)(?<!n\/)` by `(?<!n\/?)` but you could try.

Comment: This removes the `/` from `n/a`.